# Where is the dependent clause in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

My friend asked me to underline the dependent clause in the following sentence ;

- **My hope is that everyone will come to the party**.
- I told her that the whole sentence is an independent clause in which the *that everyone will come to the party* acts as a dependent clause since it fills the gap of the subject complement, but she still thinks that the dependent clause is *My hope is that* because it doesn't stand alone and the rest *everyone will come to the party* does.
- Am I right ?. If not, help me to figure out where the dependent clause is and why. Also, why is my friend's point of view wrong/right?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right: the whole sentence is an independent clause, one of whose constituents is the dependent clause introduced with *that*. *My hope is that* isn't a clause or even a constituent.

Answer (score 1):

> My hope is **that everyone will come to the party.**

You're right. The emboldened part is the dependent clause because it cannot stand alone: **that everyone will come to the party*  is not a complete sentence.

*My hope is that* cannot stand alone not because it's a dependent clause, but because it does not form a constituent, that is, a group of words functioning as a unit.